# is there any way where i can change the way .mapFrom method (in io.vertx.core.json.JsonObject) is acting through objectmapper or can mock it?

Tags: java, json, mocking, objectmapper, localdate

The error i am facing is *java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Java 8 date/time type `java.time.LocalDateTime` not supported by default: add Module “com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype:jackson-datatype-jsr310” to enable handling* , to resolve this i have included the dependency mentioned above and also made the changes in the object mapper to register(new javaTimeModule()), it is working after making some changes( i am writing tests)..

The problem is that the file i am working on converts java object to a JSon object using mapFrom method mentioned in *import io.vertx.core.json.JsonObject* like JsonObject.mapFrom(class) but the objectmapper is of no help here, to resolve the error i have to use a method from objectmapper to get the jsonObject then only it is working, but i came to know that i cannot make any change in that file( i am writing test and i cannot mock JsonObject.mapFrom(class). So, is there any way where i can change the way .mapFrom function is acting through objectmapper..

the error is also resolved by using annotations, but then also i have to make changes in main files which i don't have the permission for..

Also any way where i can mock such methods as it is being called on a class directly?

Here's the code:
In Class1:

```
Public void getSomething(Request request){
      JsonObject jsonObject = JsonObject.mapFrom(helper.class);
      //further use of json object
```

In helper class:

```
    public helper{
        LocalDateTime createdAt = LocalDate.now()
       //this is giving the Java 8, localDateTime error
    }
```

Now, i have to test getSomething, but i cannot mock the JsonObject.mapFrom(helper.class)
So either i am using annotations on CreatedAt or using object mapper to convert java object to json object with writeValueAsString then parsing and for this i have to comment the mapFrom method(which i can't do)..

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow, can you provide your code and [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)?

Answer (score 0):

I solved the issue by just mocking the mapFrom method on JavaObject using mockStatic, other solution was to change the main code such that it uses objectmapper to convert java object to jsonObject and then use the jsr310 module to register the new javaTimeModules()...